# What belt-drive compatible frame and belt-drive kit would you recommend?

Tags: frames, build

I would like to build a custom belt-drive bike for my daily commute. I am looking for a frame and a belt-drive kit for a total budget of about 500$.

I ride all year long, and winters here (Montreal, Canada) are pretty hard on bikes, so I need a simple yet robust frame. Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep in mind that any frame you buy must be designed for a belt, unless you're planning to go at it with a hacksaw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be a bit out of luck with that price range if you hope to get the whole kit.  The Gates belt, cog, and "chain"-ring retail online for over $200 by themselves.

That said, there are some options if you are clever and dedicated. If you're able to find one of the old 90's mountain bikes with [elevated chainstays](http://www.google.com/search?q=elevated+chainstay) you can use one of the expensive ($125-$150) eccentric bottom brackets that mount in a normal 68mm shell for tension.  A 90's Nishiki should be fairly cheap, so you'd eke in just under your total price.  It's also fair to say that your bike would be a unique build.

Alternatively, if you have access to an affordable machinist, start with an inexpensive frame that has thick track-style dropouts. Modifying them into a variant of the [old Spot-style](http://www.flickr.com/photos/singlespeedmaniac/2826348686/) dropouts should be relatively easy with a dremel, some taps, and a skilled hand. This avoids the significant cost of the S&S couplers used by most belt-drive modifications.

Unfortunately, unless the frame was purpose-built for a belt, you're going to be stuck modifying it. There are few, if-any, belt-specific frames in the market now, which keeps prices high.  The proper modifications either require an expensive S&S coupler or new dropouts, which are expensive to add aftermarket.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting an existing frame/bike if you have one (or can pick one up cheap). It would work best if you had a singlespeed/internal hub geared donor bike.

You'd need to:

1. Replace your chain ring
2. Replace the chain with a belt
3. Replace your rear cog
4. Cut the rear stay and insert a joiner (the most complicated task)

You might be able to either do the work yourself or find someone locally who can convert an existing bike. It sounds like a fun project!

[St Kilda cycles](http://www.stkildacycles.com.au/gates-belt-drive-) (yes, I know they're almost certainly not convenient to you) can convert an existing bike to be belt driven. I just gave them a call and they cut the frame at the rear stay and insert a joiner, then replace the chainring, rear cog and chain for a belt. They're quoting $850 to $1000 (AUD) for all the parts and labour - the variance is because depending on the frame they can use an off the shelf frame joiner or whether they have to machine one up themselves.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ih-5yiRz-g) of someone doing a conversion.
[Here's another thead](http://www.bicycles.net.au/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=36624) discussion options and pros/cons

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a frame price, but there are good reviews on the [Spot Coyote belt](http://spotbrand.com/bikes/product-page/coyote-belt/) drive bikes, and the complete bike with belt drive is $1100 USD.

They also make Ti frames with the same idea, but higher priced of course.

I would expect that the frame would be around $450-500. Your budget might be a touch low, since any quality frame will start at this price mark, and go up, and isn't likely to include the belt drive kit, unless you buy the complete bike.